# Integration paradox

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

Yesterday i was doing a question where when you integrate **Sinx dx** from 0 to 90 degree you get **-1+c** as answer and for 90 to 180 you get **1+c** as answer and when integrate it for 0 to pi you have 2 as answer but when add up individual integrated answer sum would be zero since c=0 cuz there is no vertical shift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remarks: you should not have $c$ (arbitrary constant) when you deal with definite integral.

Also potential mistake in your first integral:
$$\int_{0^\circ}^{90 ^\circ} \sin x dx = [-\cos x]|_{0^\circ}^{90^\circ}=0-(-1)=1$$